# Blockchain and smart contract beginner

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am a newbie in programming using solidity to create smart contracts. Could you please share some advice on what path i should follow if I wanted to be an expert within a year? I have experience in java. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of learning solidity the same way there are many ways of learning anything in life, mine was reading Ethereum's docs to conceptually understand what im doing, then reading solidy's docs and doing tiny scripts and examples and running them on [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/).

Yet, at the time i was doing that, i didn't knew [this](https://kernel.community/en/resources/smart-contracts/) existed, it might smoother the road for you!

Wish you good luck with it! Since you come with a background in Java, Solidity might be confusing at first since its a language based on the likes of Javascript and C++.